# How do I stop authentication of my paypal account using adaptive payments?

Tags: php, soap, paypal

Using the Adaptive Payments with the Pay method I managed to get a script working where a user can deposit money from my account to theirs through php but I have to enter my password even though it is using my api credentials. How can I stop it from asking me for my password every time? This is my code:

```
<?php

require_once '../../../lib/AdaptivePayments.php';
require_once 'web_constants.php';

session_start();

            try {


                   $serverName = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
                   $serverPort = $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];
                                                                            $url=dirname('http://'.$serverName.':'.$serverPort.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

                   $returnURL = $url."/PaymentDetails.php";
                   $cancelURL = $url. "/SetPay.php" ;
                   $currencyCode="USD";  //$_REQUEST['currencyCode'];
                   $email="qwom_1315508825_biz@btinternet.com";
                   $preapprovalKey = '';    
                   $requested='';
                   $receiverEmail='';
                   $amount='';
                   $count= count($_POST['receiveremail']);


                    //pay details//
                    $payRequest = new PayRequest();
                    $payRequest->actionType = "PAY";
                    $payRequest->currencyCode = "USD";

                    $receiver1 = new receiver();
                    $receiver1->email = "cam_1315509411_per@btinternet.com";
                    $receiver1->amount = "5.00";
                    $payRequest->receiverList = new ReceiverList();
                    $payRequest->receiverList = array($receiver1);

                    $payRequest->returnUrl = $returnURL;
                    $payRequest->senderEmail = "qwom_1315508825_biz@btinternet.com";
                    $payRequest->feesPayer = "SENDER";
                    $payRequest->cancelUrl = $cancelURL;

                    $payRequest->requestEnvelope = new RequestEnvelope();
                    $payRequest->requestEnvelope->errorLanguage = "en_US";
                    $payRequest->requestEnvelope->detailLevel = "ReturnAll";
                    //end pay details//



                   $ap = new AdaptivePayments();
                   $response=$ap->Pay($payRequest);

                   if(strtoupper($ap->isSuccess) == 'FAILURE')
                    {
                        $_SESSION['FAULTMSG']=$ap->getLastError();
                        $location = "APIError.php";
                        header("Location: $location");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $_SESSION['payKey'] = $response->payKey;
                        if($response->paymentExecStatus == "COMPLETED")
                        {
                            $location = "PaymentDetails.php";
                            header("Location: $location");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            /*$token = $response->payKey;
                            $payPalURL = PAYPAL_REDIRECT_URL.'_ap-payment&paykey='.$token;
                            header("Location: ".$payPalURL);*/
                            echo $response->paymentExecStatus;
                        }
                    }
            }
            catch(Exception $ex) {

                $fault = new FaultMessage();
                $errorData = new ErrorData();
                $errorData->errorId = $ex->getFile() ;
                $errorData->message = $ex->getMessage();
                $fault->error = $errorData;
                $_SESSION['FAULTMSG']=$fault;
                $location = "APIError.php";
                header("Location: $location");
            }

?>
```

It uses the Adaptive Payments Soap API. The credentials are in the included files.

Answer (score 0):

That's intended functionality. 
Since you're using the Pay method, it naturally assumes it's a normal transaction rather than a 'deposit'.

You'd want to look at the PayPal MassPay API instead.
See https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/mass-pay as well as https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/masspay-api-nvp for the NVP API documentation.

There's also some sample code up at https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_code [(php sample here)](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/nvp_MassPay_php.txt)

Comment: I can't get masspay to work because of my account status. Why doesn't it ask for authentication in the apigee console? Surely there must be a way.

Comment: If by 'authentication' you mean, does a buyer need to log in to his/her account in order to draw funds and send them to a receiver, then yes.

As for MassPay: MassPay is now enabled by default in Sandbox when you create a new sandbox test account. It can be enabled on your Live account with a simple call to PayPal Customer Service.

Comment: MassPay? As said, PayPal Customer Service can easily enable it for you.

Comment: No they cant. They said it would be done in three days twice now. Their customer service is useless.